# Curl not posting data to remote server , using php-curl

Tags: php, curl

I have set up local servers on virtual machine , These are two Ubuntu VMs which are connected on Virtualbox as Internal Network and Bridged adapter. I have hosted my site on a local dhcp server (internal network)  with addresses 10.0.0.3 and 10.0.0.4 . I have hosted my web pages on apache2 servers on both the machines . I have verified that they are connected as they are pinging each other VMs . I have to send a form  data from one server to other and I am using curl for that .

My update.php file on VM1 (10.0.0.4) is :

```
<?php
if($_POST['time']){
    $time = $_POST['time'];
    $data = array('time'=>$time);

    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, '10.0.0.3/index.php');
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, TRUE);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);
    curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);
}
?>
```

And my index.php file in VM2 (10.0.0.3) is :

```
<?php 
$time = $_POST['time'];
echo $time;
?>
```

I am able to receive html form data from index.html to update.php both in VM1 (10.0.0.4) but cannot post data from update.php to index.php using method described above . Is there something else I have missed to post data to remote server using curl ?

Comment: I recommend you this magic tool https://incarnate.github.io/curl-to-php/

Comment: What is the error msg? What do [`curl_getinfo()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.curl-getinfo.php) and [`curl_error()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.curl-error.php) say? How about your logs? The answers are usually right there to see if you look.

Comment: There is no error message in curl_error(), curl_errno() is 0 . curl_getinfo() is Array ( [url] => http://10.0.0.3/index.php [content_type] => [http_code] => 0 [header_size] => 0 [request_size] => 0 [filetime] => -1 [ssl_verify_result] => 0 [redirect_count] => 0 [total_time] => 0 [namelookup_time] => 0 [connect_time] => 0 [pretransfer_time] => 0 [size_upload] => 0 [size_download] => 0 [speed_download] => 0 [speed_upload] => 0 [download_content_length] => -1 [upload_content_length] => -1 [starttransfer_time] => 0 [redirect_time] => 0 [redirect_url] => [

Comment: primary_ip] => [certinfo] => Array ( ) [primary_port] => 0 [local_ip] => [local_port] => 0 )

Comment: You can edit your question and add these details, it will be easier to read and help. But it looks like nothing is happening at all, right?  So my first guess would be to add a protocol to the URL (eg `http://`).

Comment: You could also check the Apache log on `10.0.0.3` - does your request even make it to the machine?

Answer (score 0):

make sure you use isset() in your if condition while checking if data has been posted. like given below

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['time'])){
    $time = $_POST['time'];
    $data = array('time'=>$time);

    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'http://10.0.0.3/index.php');
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, TRUE);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);
    $output = curl_exec($ch);


    curl_close($ch);
    echo $output;  
}
?>
```

Comment: Thank you but like I mentioned above , I am able to post from html form to update.php but not from update.php (on one server) to index.php (on other server) , isset() will just check If the data is posted . Is there something wrong with my curl posting code .

Comment: Can you try to replace `10.0.0.3/index.php` to `http://10.0.0.3/index.php`

Comment: given suggestion is right. please put full path not the relative while calling api.